# Is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index?

Tags: sql-server

I want to create one table named as `tbl_Ticket_Mail_Address` . While creating table showing error.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Ticket_Mail_Address] (
    [Id]           INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Designation]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Emp_ID]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Emp_Name]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Mobile]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Emp_Email]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Category]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Created_By]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Created_Date] DATE           NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [uc_tbl_Ticket_Mail_Address] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Emp_ID] ASC, [Category] ASC)
);
```

> 58,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1919, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'Emp_ID' in table 'tbl_Ticket_Mail_Address' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.
>       (58,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Ticket_Mail_Address] (
    [Id]           INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Designation]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Emp_ID]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Emp_Name]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Mobile]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Emp_Email]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Category]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Created_By]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Created_Date] DATE           NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [uc_tbl_Ticket_Mail_Address] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Emp_ID] ASC, [Category] ASC)
);
```

> (58,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
>       (58,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
>   An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

Comment: Do you really want people inserting the complete works of shakespeare into e.g. `Mobile`? Pick *sensible* data lengths for your columns rather than just `nvarchar(max)` across the board and, assuming `Emp_ID` comes down to a sensible size, the problem should disappear.

Comment: ID columns are typically numeric. Why do you use nvarchar for `Emp_ID` ?

Answer (score 22):

SQL Server doesn't allow you to create a Unique index using a `nvarchar(max)` column. As D_T_U commented, choose a smaller size, e.g. `nvarchar(100)` and you will be able to create the index.

Naturally, the column size needs to fit in with your requirements, so 100 is just an example.

**Bonus info**: When creating the index, keep in mind that the size of the combined index values must not exceed 900 bytes. Each `nvarchar` character will use 2 bytes, so you can at most have a combined size of `nvarchar(450)`. For example, in your case you could have

```
[Emp_ID] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Category] NVARCHAR (400)
```

It is permissible, but dangerous, to declare larger sizes for nvarchar columns as long as the data on any given row does not exceed 900 bytes. For example, if you declare both columns as `nvarchar(300)`, you will get the following message:

> Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index
>   'uc_tbl_Ticket_Mail_Address' has maximum length of 1200 bytes. For
>   some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will
>   fail.

Answer (score 1):

Check [CREATE INDEX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) statement in MSDN.

> Columns that are of the large object (LOB) data types ntext, text,
>   varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), xml, or image cannot be
>   specified as key columns for an index.

To solve the problem itself, refer @Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also happen if your index column has been defined as SPARSE.

```
[hash] VARBINARY(32) SPARSE NULL -- Fail
[hash] VARBINARY(32) NULL        -- Success
```

> (597,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1919, Level 16,
>   State 2, Line 1 Column 'hash' in table 'Document_JSON' is of a type
>   that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.
>
> (597,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.